# Laravel : image not displaying only when php variable is input in path

Tags: laravel, image

I am working on a Laravel project. My picture is displaying when I put this code

```
<img class="first-slide" src="{{asset('images/auto.jpeg')}} " >
```

Looking at the inspector I have this :

[image]

However when I try to pass a php variable in the link of the picture (for instance :

```
<img class="first-slide" src="{{asset('images/'.$machines_all->imagesrc.'.jpeg')}} " >
```

The picture is not displaying and I have this in the inspector :

[image]

I also tried passing the whole string in the php variable (images/auto.jpeg) but it is still not displaying)

Any hint is welcome

Comment: Don't use `<?= ... ?>` inside blade, instead concatenate the variable. Why post images of code???

Comment: thanks it works. sorry for bad formatting